# Failure in SSIS connection manager

Tags: database, ssis, informix, database-administration

I'm new to SSIS. I have tried to use the ODBC connection manager that was already in the list to extract the source data, but failed with the following error message:
`The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager failed with error code 0xC0014009.`

The ODBC connection manager is connected to IBM informix.

I have referred to the existing projects and found that they all used the same connection manager and it works fine.
I have tried the 'Test Connection' and it went well. But when I execute the package, error came out.
What could be the possible reason that I can't use the existing connection manager?

Comment: 32 vs 64 bit? You have a bug in your code? The credentials aren't coming across in your call to the odbc data source? Those are my top 3 but questions about code that show no code are notoriously difficult to solve

Comment: @billinkc I don’t think 32 vs 64 bit is the problem, because the projects are all executed using the same machine. I pulled the whole table through instead of using sql command, is it the bug you mean in this step? Can you also tell me what are the credentials that you mean?

Comment: As bilinkc said, double check that the ODBC DSN you created are in either 32-bits or 64-bits.. The DSN needs to match whatever mode you are running SSIS job (check the screensthots on this post https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/440452/ssis-error-the-acquireconnection-method-call-to-th.html)
Also, make sure the DSN are created as System DSN, as SSIS agent usually run as System Account, not as the loged user.